# Issue with JS Mouse Wheel Event Delta

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, zooming

I am working on a project that uses mouse events to zoom and pan a `canvas`. They work fine independently, however, I would like the `canvas` to pan towards the cursor while zooming.

My objective: have the cursor location be where you are zooming towards. I have been playing around with this for some time and I was able to get it *working*.

I did notice something odd. If you reload the page with the cursor over the `canvas` panning while zooming did not work. What would happen instead, is, the `canvas` would zoom in but `displacement.x` and `displacement.y` would be unchanged.

I believe it is because of `event.delta`. It is as if `event.delta = 0` upon reload only if the cursor location is over the `canvas`.

Here are my mouse events:

```
function panCanvasOnZoom(event) {

    var sensitivity = 0.05 * event.delta;
    var halfSize = { w: canvasSize.w / 2, h: canvasSize.h / 2 }
    var centerOrientedMouse = { x: halfSize.w - pmouseX, y: halfSize.h - pmouseY }
    var relativeMousePercentage = { x: pmouseX / canvasSize.w, y: pmouseY / canvasSize.h }

    var panX = (halfSize.w - pmouseX) * sense * relativeMousePercentage.x;
    var panY = (halfSize.h - pmouseY) * sense * relativeMousePercentage.y;

    panX += panX * relativeMousePercentage.x;
    panY += panY * relativeMousePercentage.y;
    displacement.x += panX;
    displacement.y += panY;

} 

function mouseWheel(event) {

    if (pmouseX < 0 || pmouseX > canvasSize.w ||
        pmouseY < 0 || pmouseY > canvasSize.h)
        return;

    panCanvasOnZoom(event);
    displacement.z += 0.05 * event.delta;
    displacement.z = constrain(displacement.z, 0.05, 9.00);

    return false;
}
```

I am calculating the sensitivity using the `event.delta`. When I noticed this issue, I began debugging and realized that if I replaced `var sensitivity = 0.05 * event.delta` with `var sensitivity = 0.05` it would essentially replicate the cursor issue.

My question is, is there a way to circumvent `event.delta = 0`? I do not mean an `if` statement to check for the condition. I mean something along the lines of setting `event.delta` to something besides `0` upon initializing.

Also, if you see any improvements regarding the efficiency of `panCanvasOnZoom()` please post those.

Comment: Why are you using `event.delta` instead of `event.deltaX` or `event.deltaY`? I didn't even know `event.delta` is a thing